# @Secured("<new_role>") shows access_denied

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jhipster

I have created a project using generator-jhipster with mongo database.

I wanted to add a new role in `JHI_AUTHORITY` so I have inserted a new record in `JHI_AUTHORITY` document in mongo `{"_id" : "ROLE_MANAGER"}`

Now I want that only user with either `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_MANAGER` is authorized for one of the api.
So I have added following LOC in my api:

```
@secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_MANAGER"})
```

But when I tried to access the api with user having role: `ROLE_ADMIN` it works great but with user having role: `ROLE_MANAGER`, it shows me error:

```
{ "error": "access_denied", "error_description": "Access is denied" }
```

Please let me know if there is any step that is missing?

Security Configuration Class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
            .antMatchers("/api/register")
            .antMatchers("/api/activate")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Show your security configuration class

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have added Security Configuration class in my question. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security roles have default prefix - `ROLE_`

While in your DB you need to save the roles as `ROLE_NAME` when you use them in `@Secured`, `@PreAuthorize` etc use them without the prefix (e.g. `NAME`).

Comment: I have tried your answer and use `@Secured` with `MANAGER` role without `ROLE_` prefix but it is not working. The response is `access_denied`.

Comment: are you putting the annotation on the controller itself? if you do it will never work as spring serve a proxy instead of the class itself. you need to either put it on your service layer / use an ant matcher in a configuration file / create an interface that the controller extend and put it there

Comment: I have tried using antMatchers in my configuration class with following LOC `http.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/XXX").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "MANAGER");` but this also grants access only to admin and not to manager.